# cannot store session values from json object

Tags: php, json, session-storage

I am reading values from database and would like to store the values as a session object to be reused by the code. however, the code executes fine but does not store any values in the session storage.

JS code

```
$.getJSON("sessionstore.php", {"points": myjson}, function(data){
            sessionStorage.user = data[0];
            sessionStorage.usermail = data[2];
            sessionStorage.supmail = data[4];
            sessionStorage.repsupervisor = data[3];
            sessionStorage.issupervisor = data[5];
    });

php code

<?php
include 'mydbconn.php';

if (isset($_POST["points"])) {
$points = json_decode($_POST["points"]);
}
// decode the json data that is being passed
$usrname = $points->usrname;

    $sql = "Select EmpName, EmpMail, RepSupervisor, SupMail, IsSupervisor from glusers where EmpName='$usrname'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $data = array();

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $data[] = $row; 
};
echo $data[0];
die();
?>
```

There are no errors but the code does not execute.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You are not outputting valid json. Note that `$data[0]` is a row of your result set - an array - so when you `echo` it in php you will output something like `Array`.

You need to change:

```
echo $data[0];
die();
```

to:

```
echo json_encode($data[0]);
die();
```

**Edit:** Also, you are fecthing associative arrays, so you would need to address them in your javascript as:

```
data.EmpName
data.EmpMail
// etc.
```

Comment: sorry it is echo json_econde($data);